# agm marker Agm-marker dragEnd event is not returning coordinates

Tags: angular-google-maps

Angular google maps agm marker drag end event not returning coordinates

```
<agm-map [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude" [zoom]="zoom">
        <agm-marker [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude" [markerDraggable]="true"
           (dragEnd)="markerDragEnd($event)"></agm-marker>
    </agm-map>

 markerDragEnd($event: any) {
    console.log($event);
    this.latitude = $event.coords.lat;
    this.longitude = $event.coords.lng;
    this.getAddress(this.latitude, this.longitude);
  }
```

Comment: please any one help me

Comment: I am facing this exact same problem. Any solution yet?

Answer (score 4):

I think that in the new versions of Angular in order to have the coordinates you want, you have to do something like this:

```
$event.latLng.lat()
```

So, in your case the function markerDragEnd should look like:

```
markerDragEnd($event: any) {
    console.log('lat', $event.latLng.lat()); //to see the latitude in the console
    console.log('lng', $event.latLng.lng()); // to see the longitude in the console
    this.latitude = $event.latLng.lat();
    this.longitude = $event.latLng.lng();
    this.getAddress(this.latitude, this.longitude);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

yes now for new versions instead of `$event.coords.lt` you put :

```
$event.latLng.lat()
```

```
markerDragEnd($event: any) {
    console.log("Something ", $event);
    this.latitude = $event.latLng.lat();
    this.longitude = $event.latLng.lng();
    this.getAddress(this.latitude, this.longitude);
  }
```